# Changing Graphics32's TImgView32's resampler kernel on the fly

Tags: delphi, resampling, graphics32

I want to change resampling kernel of Graphics32's TImgView32 on the fly.
However there is no visible difference. Here's the code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImgView321.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('1.bmp');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImgView321.Scale := ImgView321.Scale*2;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImgView321.Scale := ImgView321.Scale/2;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImgView321.Bitmap.ResamplerClassName := 'TKernelResampler'; 
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImgView321.Bitmap.ResamplerClassName := 'TNearestResampler'
end;
```

Comment: So where is the problem? (Btw.: It should be possible to use the same event handler for both up and down).

Comment: I changed the code to be even simpler. I don't see any change how the image is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose 'TKernelResampler' it is important to specify the kernel that is used. The default is TBoxKernel with a result that is nearly identical with the 'TNearestResampler'

In fact it is identical from a visual perspective, just a different computation.

Try to use the 'TCubicKernel' or 'TLanczosKernel'. For more control you can also pick the 'THermiteKernel' or 'TAlbrechtKernel', which has two control parameters (instead of just one).

Comment: I tried your solution but it's still exactly as TNearestResampler. Also I don't have TLanczosKernel in the options in Design Time: https://i.imgur.com/lJ45WYz.png

Comment: You have to use TKernelResampler. With this you can change the kernel (not the resampler) to TLanczosKernel. [assuming you are using the latest GR32 v2.0)